# Change language problems with recycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with (left bar) is a `"android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"` When I try change text, my lateral not responding, I think that not load correctly.

Only exist a Activity, the rest are fragments, in my activity have "left bar"

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    change text from programatically    
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    change text from programatically
```

I try change text, but not work , I think that not is called, because my activity is only called the first time

I have a control of fragment called "FragmentReutil2" have all beginTransaction. Into this method I put loadLanguage and .setadapter(again)

Note:

- (OnResume) only call 1 time (firsttime)
- My method call every times to transition fragments. FragmentReutil2
- All fragment Works correctly without left bar

Comment: I'm confused... Are you saying you're trying to change the text in some item in the list and it's not reflected on the UI?

Comment: Yes, example : en (English), es (Spanish), ca (Catalan) ... or other languages, but my list never change text dinamically in my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure what you're actually asking, but I think your problem is that you're not calling one of the following after you've changed the data that is reflected on the UI.

- [`adapter.notifyDataChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) if you don't know which ones have changed or all of them have changed.
- [`adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) if only one item has changed and you know which one.
- [`adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(start, count)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) if multiple consecutive items have changed.

There's also multiple other methods that you can use to inform the adapter of data changes, removals and additions, just check the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)